# PYTHON: Making an array with n-many elements

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to write a program that will first ask for the number of inputs, then will ask for the value of each input. I need to find the mean and root-mean-square of the values from input, so I am trying to make an array of n-many (usually 2, but up to 6) elements.
I am having trouble setting up this array since I don't know how many elements it will have.
I have tried several different ways to make it work. This is my latest attempt:

```
N = input("How many inputs: ")
i=1
a = []
while i <= N:
    a.append = input("Enter value for flux: ")
    i = i+1
```

Surely there is something simple that I am missing; this seems like something that would be common.

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the API for `list.append`. As it is, you are throwing away that list's `append` method and replacing it with the user's input, repeatedly. That line should be as follows:

```
a.append(input("Enter value for flux: "))
```

The user's input is passed as an argument to the `a.append` method, appending it to that list.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing append= that is not valid, try it like this:

```
N = input("How many inputs: ")
i=1
a = []
while i <= N:
    value = input("Enter value for flux: ")
    a.append(value)
    i = i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the range can help you. Also be sure to int the answer and to try/except the `int`. I leave that to you.

```
a = []
for i in range(N):
    a.append(int(input('> ')))
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

there you go.

```
N = input("How many inputs: ")
a = []
for _ in xrange(N):
    a.append(input("Enter value for flux: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the inputs to integer.

```
N = int(input("How many inputs: "))
a = []
for elem in range(N):
    a.append(int(input("Enter value for flux: ")))
```